# How can I prevent vCloud credentials from leaking during Terraform execution?

Tags: terraform, credentials

My team has provisioned developer workstations. During the last provisions, it was discovered that an admin could run "ps-ef" and see the vCloud credentials that were provided to instruct Terraform to talk to vCloud. Would a solution be to automatically answer prompts from Terraform, when variables/ credentials are not provided as CLI arguments to the Terraform command?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the various credentials as environment variables, according to the [provider documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vcd/index.html).

That won't stop someone with root privileges being able to see them by inspecting `/proc` but it will stop the credentials being visible with `ps`.